# 13.04; frequent freezes under gnome-shell, gnome, unity

Tags: nvidia, freeze, gdm

I just upgraded 12.10-->13.04 on my Dell Precision:

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 0 @ 3.60GHz
- NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

I can login via gdm -- by default I use gnome-shell.  Within (I'd guess) 30-45 seconds the system freezes. And it really is frozen; e.g. if I'm logged in by ssh from my laptop, I'm frozen there as well.

I get the same behavior when I choose in gdm to login using "gnome (fallback)" or  unity.

But if I Ctl-Alt F2 and login through the console, I have no freezing-difficulties at all.

I've looked through /var/log/syslog*, and I do not see a culprit.

I was not having any difficulties with 12.10.

I was using xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, and I wondered at first if that was the culprit.
So I tried installing the nvidia-current (and the packages that dragged in). But this had no effect -- the freezing behaviour was the same (I've now changed back to nouveau - the console is nicer...)

One more data point, which is probably a red herring. I did the upgrade two days ago, and had problems more-or-less immediately. I noticed that a certain hardware sensor was starting up (psensor) each time I logged in, and its launch seemed to coincide with
the freezes I was having. So I logged in remotely and removed all the psensor packages.
Things seemed better - for a day I had no freezes at all, so I thought I had solved the problem. But it has now returned.

I suspect that my question is going to be *closed* and I'm going to be told to file a bug report, and I understand. But I still think there are some "askubuntu" questions here:

- For one thing: I don't know the culprit -- what should I file a bug report against?
- And: I'm hoping for advice/suggestions. Would it help to try to use an older kernel? I haven't tried that yet (mainly because I suspect it would cause a big mess of "apt" related dependency problems).

Comment: If you login via the console and then start up a graphical environment manually, does it proceed to crash?

Comment: @Sam: yes, it does.

Answer (score 0):

To report a bug to Psensor, please read: http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/doc/faq.html#S_BugReport

I doubt Psensor itself can be the cause of a computer freeze. There might a bug that I am not aware causing a DE freeze but certainly not a kernel crash.

In the past, there was an access violation between the lmsensors library used by Psensor and the ACPI but AFAIK it is fixed in recent releases. See: http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter3#Mysensorshavestoppedworkinginkernel2.6.31 .

BTW, I guess it is not related to Psensor as you seem to say that after psensor removal the issue still exist.

You should first look at the log files in /var/log, mainly the syslog.* and dmesg.* ones after the crash occurs.